# fatal: protocol error: unexpected 'Error running git: fork/exec /usr/bin/git-receive-pack: no such file or directory'

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I'm getting this error when I'm pushing my local branch on to the remote.
I don't see git-receive-pack in git config as well.
What is this git-receive-pack ? and how do I fix this error?

```
fatal: protocol error: unexpected 'Error running git: fork/exec /usr/bin/git-receive-pack: no such file or directory'
```

Comment: If you find a soluction, please don't forget to post here.

Comment: seems like this is an issue with bitbucket https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/fatal-protocol-error-unexpected-Error-running-git-fork-exec-usr/qaq-p/1765971

Answer (score -2):

Push worked after doing a `git fetch`

This is an ongoing issue with bitbucket recently.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/fatal-protocol-error-unexpected-Error-running-git-fork-exec-usr/qaq-p/1765971